# How to create a new post using an async function after login into a page

Tags: javascript, form-submit, async.js, bearer-token

I need help creating a form where a user would log in and create their own post after having been verified they've logged in with a token. Essentially I'm trying to create a form that would submit the values of the input to create a post on a page but would only display the form if the user is logged in.

here is my html:

```
 <div class = "addNewPost">
    <div class = "content">
      <h3>Create New Post</h3>
      <form class="" action="" method="">

            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" required="">
            <!-- <h5>This is a required field</h5> -->
          </br>
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea id="description" columns="40" rows="5"></textarea>
          </br>
            <label for="location">Location</label>
            <textarea id="location" columns="40" rows="1"></textarea>
          </br>       
            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <textarea id="price" columns="40" rows="1"></textarea>
           </br>          
           <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Shipping Available</label>
          </div>
          
          
            <div class="actions">
            <button class="create-newpost">
                Add
            </button>
      
            <button class="action cancel-new-post">
             <span class="action-text">Cancel</span>
             </button>
            </div>
```

---

here is my JS :

```
const newPost = async post => {
try {
    const response = await fetch(`${ API }/posts`, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': `Bearer ${state.token}`
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({post}) 
    });
    const addingPost = await response.json();
    console.log('addingPost: ',addingPost.data.post);
    state.posts.unshift(addingPost.data.post)
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're facing?

Comment: @CertainPerformance No only using JS I have a global variable called state where I have an empty string for posts which would append to my posts.

Comment: @SerShubham I'm running into an issue of how to get it to append to my data.post  from the submit form.